# How to handle fragments sharing same viewmodel and livedata cause same action on both fragments?

Tags: android, fragment, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a SignUpFragment in which Firebase is used for signing up and a livedata observer is there.

SignUpFragment

```
    viewModel.userMediatorLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        Timber.i("Screen", this.javaClass.simpleName)
        if (it.status != null && it.message != null) {
            btn_sign_up.showSnack(it.message)
            if (it.status) {
                PreferenceHelper.userPassword = tie_password.getTrimmedText()
                returnToLoginScreen()
            }
        }
    })
```

When a user successfully sign up, I'm navigating him to the Login Screen, but in login screen there's also a livedata observer which uses the same variable.

LoginFragment

```
    // this observer is used also for listening to Firebase Login
    viewModel.userMediatorLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        Timber.i("Screen", this.javaClass.simpleName)
        if (it.status != null && it.message != null) {
            btn_login.showSnack(it.message)
            if (it.status) {
                PreferenceHelper.userPassword = tie_password.getTrimmedText()
                context?.startActivity(HomeActivity::class.java)
                requireActivity().finish()
            }
        }
    })
```

Here you can see that the condition will be true for both cases and Login screen switches to HomeScreen.

How can I handle such a situation?
Please note that I'm sharing viewmodel using

```
 private val viewModel: AuthViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Also replaced `this` with `viewLifecycleOwner` but still no hope.

Comment: So basically you want to share your ViewModel and it's content between fragments, right?

Comment: And also can you show how have you initialized your viewmodel in the fragments?

Comment: @ParagPawar No, I've a common livedata variable for handling the results of login and signup, when signup is complete I'm navigating to login screen, but the livedata observer in login is also true, because of signup is true.

Comment: Okay so if I understood correctly, you want the user to log in after he completes the registration, but it's going straight to the home screen because you're observing the same MediatorLiveData, right?

Comment: @ParagPawar You got it!

Comment: you can create two different variables or you can make variable which will tell you which button click based on you can perform your task. inside If condition inside the observe you can check the type.

Comment: Should be using `viewLifecycleOwner`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce also tried that. I forgot to update the code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so continuing our discussion here, you're sharing ViewModel between fragments, so when you're observing the particular live data in the fragment, you're not reinitializing it instead you're using the same instance. So there can be 2 ways you can handle this. One: Stop sharing your ViewModel, or remove your observer as soon as you change the flag.

this is the 2nd way:

```
val mUserData = viewModel.userMediatorLiveData

val mUserObserver = Observer {
    Timber.i("Screen", this.javaClass.simpleName)
    if (it.status != null && it.message != null) {
        btn_login.showSnack(it.message)
        if (it.status) {
            PreferenceHelper.userPassword = tie_password.getTrimmedText()
            context?.startActivity(HomeActivity::class.java)
            requireActivity().finish()
            //notice this
            mUserData.removeObserver(mUserObserver)
        }
    }
}

mUserData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, mUserObserver)
```

You might have to define your mUserObserver first(outside the function).

Try this and let me know

Comment: I think this won't work in your condition, because firebase will always tell you that user is logged in until you explicitly log out the user. Can you share your firebase code as well, so that I'll have clear understanding of it

Comment: When I call this observer, it has the old values, which is set to true in Sign up screen

Comment: Yes because it's getting data from firebase and firebase will always return you the logged-in status, please post your code related userMediatorLiveData implementation in ViewModel.